# Golang more than one idle connection per host

Tags: http, go, network-programming

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost controls the number of keep alive connections per host. The problem I’m having is that I don’t see how the number of keep alive connections per host can exceed 1.

If one is already cached, `getConn` will return the cached connection. If there’s no cached connection it will create a new one.

How could there be more than one per host?

Comment: How would you make concurrent requests if there were only 1 connection possible?

Comment: I agree that it should be allowed but I don’t see the code path that allows it.

Comment: If you make multiple concurrent requests to the same host, multiple connections need to be opened, and `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` is the max number kept open after they complete. It's the same general code path for any request, what exactly are you looking for?